# how to execute on a dataset stored as a string in R

Tags: r, parsing, eval

df is a dataframe in the workspace.
I have a list called metadata of the form:

```
metadata$dfname = "df"
metadata$otherinfo = otherinfo
```

I want to make operations on df of the form:

```
rm(df)
```

I can get the dataset name as:

```
eval(parse(text="metadata$dfname"))
```

which returns:

```
"df"
```

How do I make operations on df? I tried multiple ways using "rm()" inside the eval and parse statement, but it would not work. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: what's the advantage of `eval(parse(text="metadata$dfname"))` over `metadata$dfname`?

Comment: the intention was to create an expression (using parse) and execute it (using eval), since the filename is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions like `ls` and `rm` have a `list` argument that lets you specify the names of objects as strings. So in this case, you want `rm(list=metadata$dfname)`.

Comment: Thanks @Hong Ooi. That works perfectly! I have accepted your answer. Do you have any idea, what works inside the statement i.e. how such nested expressions (first get df, and then rm(df)) are created and evaluated?